# How to exclude a circle from a rectangle when drawing a contour figure?

Tags: plotting

I need to draw a contour figure defined by coordinate x and y. The domain is a rectangle (-100<=x<=100,-100<=y<=100) excluding a circle (center at the origin, and radius of 5). The object function is 'z=x+y'.

What confuses me is how to exclude the circle from the rectangle. How can I draw such a contour figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) as the first argument of `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[ConditionalExpression[x + y, x^2 + y^2 >= 5^2],
  {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100},  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
ContourPlot[x + y, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 >= 5^2], 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]
```

[image]

If the smoothness of disk bothers you (it bothers me), you can cheat it like so:

```
Show[ContourPlot[x + y, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"], 
 Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, 5]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice quality of the figure! Got it~ Thank you!